# Attempting to use Internet Sharing for iOS Activation

Tags: ios, mdm, apple-configurator, configuration-profiles

I’m trying to configure iOS devices in mass. Unfortunately my team doesn’t have direct access to our company MDM, so enrollment through Configurator isn’t working.

I had the idea to use internet sharing over usb to get devices on the network and avoid having to manually enter network credentials. However when I do this the connection to the activation server keeps timing out.

Initially I thought it was something about the company network, but I get the same result when connecting the Mac to a cellular hotspot for Ethernet.

I’ve tried deploying a profile with a different network, but it somehow gets embedded in the management profile and can’t be removed once the device becomes managed.

I’ve also tried exiting Configurator to ensure it isn’t interfering with the communication.

Has anyone been able to do this successfully? Any ideas of what could be interfering with communication to the Activation Server?

Additional info: I just tested using a lightning to Ethernet adaptor on our corporate network. Taking the Mac out of the equation allowed the configuration to happen without any delays. Not sure what is impacting the traffic when it passes through the Mac.